# How to get amazon or flipkart shared product URL to my ionic application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I create an application in ionic and I need to load shared URL from amazon or flipkart product to my application.

> Ex: if we select a product in amazon or flipart and share in what's app or Facebook that time what's app or Facebook show produce details. same as need to create in my ionic application

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a wrapper for [Linkify](https://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/).

There are a couple of them for Angular so you should be able to integrate them into Ionic without too much trouble.

There is this one which is just a plain wrapper for Linkify:

- https://github.com/AnthonyNahas/ngx-linkifyjs

By default Linkify just turns text of urls into clickable text.

You have asked about showing link previews though, which this one provides:

- https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/link-preview

As you can see from the screenshot below, the text at the top is parsed and then multiple link previews are extracted and displayed below it:

[image]